# HTML Formatting Error

Tags: bug, status-completed

I tried to downvote a question. However, I don't have enough rep to do this, and I got the following message:

[image]

I'm no expert on HTML,  pretty sure the `<a href="/help/whats-reputation">reputation<a/>` is supposed to be formatted into a link.

Comment: What operating system? What browser? Please [edit] the question and make sure you also include the version. Don't answer in the comments.

Comment: @David in this case it doesn't matter which system or browser OP has, that's just global bug with html entities

Comment: [Companion report on network-wide Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377743/you-can39t-vote-for-your-own-post)

Comment: @nicael - The browser does seem matter since I wasn’t able to reproduce the issue on Safari on iOS

Comment: @Ramhound could you post a screenshot, please? I was able to reproduce on any browser, including in Safari on iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been [fixed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377743/badly-escaped-html-results-in-plain-text-instead-of-markup-in-toast-notification)

> This is now fixed, as are any other toast notifications that show that are related to voting.